# Changing collection view's isHidden property doesn't work with Search Bar cancel button

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I have a collection view that is hidden on ViewDidLoad. When a user taps on the search bar, the collection view is shown. But when I click on the cancel button in the search bar, the collection view is not hidden. I read on other posts to use .alpha = 0 to hide a view and that works. My questions are:

- Why isHidden not working and .alpha is?
- Is collection view still the active layer if I use .alpha = 0?

Here is the code:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    collectionView.isHidden = true // This doesn't work
    //collectionView.alpha = 0 // This works
}

func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    collectionView.isHidden = false // This doesn't work
    //collectionView.alpha = 1  // This works
    return true
}
```

Animated GIF showing app working by changing alpha channel to 1 and 0
[image: Animated GIF showing app working properly with .alpha]

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

This hidden property works best on `UIView`s (while used for many other things). It's best to embed your `collectionView` inside a view if you want to use the hidden property.

> The default value of this property is false. As an optimization, the
> collection view might not create the corresponding view when the value
> of this property is true. Because there might not be a view, hidden
> elements do not participate in hit testing for the collection view.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewlayoutattributes/1535336-ishidden